# Should I use a different user other than the first one that is created during the install in Lubuntu 16.04?

Tags: permissions, users, accounts

Is the first user you create, when you enter your information during the install, an admin or some kind of privileged user?

If not, is there a hidden "admin" account similar to root but with less privileges that is already created?

Should I create a regular user to use for everyday tasks or is it safe to use the first user that is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the first user you create, when you enter your information during the install, an admin or some kind of privileged user?

Yes. **By default**, the user you created during the installation is added to the [sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers) file and can execute programs with root privileges.

> If not, is there a hidden "admin" account similar to root but with less privileges that is already created?

There is no "hidden admin".

> Should I create a regular user to use for everyday tasks or is it safe to use the first user that is created?

It depends. Although the user created upon installation is granted sudo-permissions, **by default** privilege escalation prompts the user for her password. This prevents unsolicited privilege escalation and is a reasonable compromise between security and convenience.